# Не понимаю логику деления с остатком (пример простого кода внутри)

Tags: python

Прошу помощи разобраться с простым примером: предположим, пользователь ввел число 1928; в первом случае деления к переменной max1 присвоится число 8, а далее какие числа?

**Задание:** Пользователь вводит целое положительное число.
Найдите самую большую цифру в числе.
Для решения используйте цикл while и арифметические операции.

```
n = int(input("Введите целое положительное число "))
max1 = n % 10 
print(max1)
while n >= 1:
    n = n // 10  
    print(n)
    if n % 10 > max1:  
        print(n)
        print(max1)
        max1 = n % 10  
        print(max1)
    elif n > 9:
        pass
print("Максимальное цифра в числе ", max1)
```

Comment: Так а что получится, если 1928 разделить на 10 целочисленно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n // 10` - целочисленное деление

`n % 10` - остаток от целочисленного деления

1. Изначально присваиваем самой большой цифре цифру 8 - `n%10 = 8`
2. Дальше мы нацело делим наше число n на 10, получаем `n = 192`
3. Снова ищем остаток от 10, он будет равен 2 - `n%10 = 192%10 = 2`
4. В следующей итерации 192 нацело делим на 10 получаем `n = 19`
5. Ищем остаток от деления на 10, получаем 9 - `n%10 = 19%10 = 9`
6. Делим 19 на цело на 10, получаем 1, ищем остаток от деления на 10, получаем 1 - `n % 10 = 1 % 10 = 1`
   Таким образом, код перебрал все цифры в числе с помощью целочисленного деления и деления с остатком на 10 и вывел 9

Comment: Зачитали код вслух с выражением ;)